# How best to capture and move the heat from oil furnace stove pipe more efficiently throughout room

Tags: hvac, central-heating, energy-efficiency, heat

In my basement the stove pipe that goes from the oil furnace to the chimney is always hot, so I feel like I should be capturing this extra heat and moving it about the basement. How do I keep this wasted heat?

Would a copper curtain with fan or stove pipe piece with blowers on the side keep the heat from traveling up the chimney?

Will wrapping the stove pipes or fanning the pipe with copper curtain increase heat transfer?

Comment: Welcome. A small fan on low might extract a lot of heat without creating uncomfortable draft. Some photos of your situation would help us with ideas.

Comment: You keep mentioning copper, but anything that wraps the pipe effectively insulates it. If anything you'd want radiating fins that more quickly pass heat to the air.

Comment: Whatever else, don't overdo it!   Your exhaust pipe and chimney depend on the exhaust being at least a little warm to provide the proper updraft (assuming there's no exhaust blower in your furnace, which I don't recall ever seeing).

Comment: Over-doing it may also lead to problematic levels of condensation. High efficiency furnaces are designed for condensation, with means to collect it and surfaces designed to tolerate it (it can be corrosive) - a home-brew exhaust-pipe cooler won't be.